# Reducing column header names font size in kable tables in Rmarkdown (ioslides)

Tags: r, markdown, xtable, kable, ioslides

In all my tables that I'm trying to produces in ioslides I am getting a result that shows a massive column name. How do I shrink this to make the table look okay?

Here is one example, but the same thing happens with every table. What am I missing? Ideally I'd want the content in the table to be the same font size.

Markdown:

```````
## Test
``````{r, Test,echo=FALSE}
options("kableExtra.html.bsTable" = T)
kable(df, format= "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), font_size = 12.5)
```````

Image of my output:
[image: Image of my table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change row sizes by using `row_spec()`

Since the header is interpreted as the row 0 you can change your header independently to fit your needings.

Try

```
kable(df, format= "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), font_size = 12.5) %>%
  row_spec(0, font_size=9)
```

for more settings check [row_spec](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.1.0/topics/row_spec)